# How can the hasNext methods of Scanner "not advance past any input"?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputstream, system.in

In the `hasNext` and `hasNextXxx` methods of `java.util.Scanner` it reads:

> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan. **The scanner does not advance past any input.**

How can the scanner not advance through the input stream while it clearly has to check if a next token is present in the input (as `Readable` or `InputStream`)?

Comment: Isn't it the same concept as `peek()`

Comment: You mean the `peek` as used in the Lambda streams API?

Comment: Yes, my first thought went that way

Comment: I guess it's the same thing, but I hope that `peek` doesn't have the same kind of documentation mistakes (or at least badly written statements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two notions of "advancing through input" being conflated here.

The first notion is reading more bytes from the InputStream, which of course the Scanner has to do in order to test whether it has a next token. The Scanner does this by buffering the new bytes read from the InputStream, so that those bytes can later be read from the Scanner when necessary. We could call this "advancing through the input stream".

The second notion is advancing the position of the next byte to be consumed from the buffer. This happens when you call methods like `next` which consume tokens, to mark that those bytes have been "used" and shouldn't be read again; calling `next` advances the position in the buffer. We could call this "advancing through the input in the Scanner's buffer".

The documentation's statement *"The scanner does not advance past any input"* is the second notion; calling `hasNext` doesn't advance through the Scanner's buffer, it merely reads more bytes from the input stream into the buffer. To verify this, you can try creating an input stream, calling `hasNext`, and then reading the next character (rather than the next token) using `nextInLine`:

```java
> InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("hello world".getBytes());
> Scanner sc = new Scanner(is);
> sc.next()
"hello" (String)
> sc.hasNext()
true (boolean)
> sc.nextInLine(".")
" " (String)
```

So calling `hasNext` not only doesn't consume the next token, but it also doesn't consume the delimiter before the next token. The Scanner has not *"advance[d] past any input"* in this sense.

Answer (score 3):

It **does** advance through the input stream. It just doesn't advance past the next input, from the `Scanner` and `Scanner` user's point of view. So arguably this piece of documentation is badly worded.

This can be easily tested by putting just a single token in a stream, and then calling `hasNext` for that token. In that case, you'll find that the stream is exhausted after calling `hasNext`.

In other words, the `Scanner` buffers the peeked characters internally, including any delimiter characters. Subsequent calls will then start out from the buffered characters. `Scanner` doesn't rely on any buffering provided by the underlying stream.

This text is at least present until Java 12.

Example code:

```
Reader stringReader = new StringReader("Single line");

Scanner firstScanner = new Scanner(stringReader);
// prints out true because there is a first line
System.out.println(firstScanner.hasNextLine());

Scanner secondScanner = new Scanner(stringReader);
// prints out false because the scanner has advanced the reader
// ... through the character stream generated from the string
System.out.println(secondScanner.hasNextLine());

// prints out true because the first scanner is buffering the input
System.out.println(firstScanner.hasNextLine());
```

---

It also contains other documentation issues with `hasNext`, for instance in the documentation of the `Scanner` class itself it reads:

> The `next()` and `hasNext()` methods and their companion methods (such as `nextInt()` and `hasNextInt()`) first skip any input that matches the delimiter pattern, **and then attempt to return the next token**.

obviously the last part is not true for `hasNext()`. This looks like `hasNext` has been shoe-horned into an existing sentence.

Comment: how come you make a question and answer it ?

Comment: @ZOLDIK I first searched on SO, then didn't find the information. So I decided to test it and write a question and answer. Next step is to file a bug report against the documentation, I guess. Of course, feel free to write a better answer, I'll be happy to accept it :)

Comment: @ZOLDIK It's encouraged: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I don't think this is true; e.g. `Scanner sc = new Scanner("Hello world"); sc.next(); sc.hasNext(); sc.findInLine(".")` the last call returns `" "`, not `"w"`, so the `hasNext` call doesn't advance the input to the start of the next token.

Comment: I think you are entirely missing the "input stream" part of the question and answer. A string is not a stream and doesn't contain any state. If you have any recommendations for changes in the question or answer after re-reading it I'll be happy to take them into account.

Comment: The exact same behaviour occurs if you put the string into a ByteArrayInputStream first.

Comment: You are only calling methods on `sc` and I clearly said that there is no advance in the input / input tokens from the Scanner's point of view. But you've got a point about *what* is being buffered maybe - if it includes delimiter characters, for instance - I'll investigate.